# How to check if Typescript AST node is a javascript native function?

Tags: javascript, typescript, parsing, abstract-syntax-tree

I would like to check if an AST node in TypeScript corresponds to a valid Javascript function (and not a custom method, for example).

It would be something like this :

```
function isJavascriptFunction(node: ts.Node): boolean {
    // -----
}
```

For example, if I have the code

```
const a = b.slice(1);
```

the AST will be like this :

```
CallExpression
    PropertyAccessExpression
        Identifier
        Identifier
```

The second Identifier is the javascript function "slice", so my function should return `true`.

Do you have an idea about it ?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

finally, I found a solution.

At first, I need to check if my Node is the second son of a `PropertyAccessExpression` and if its grandparent is a `CallExpression`.

With these information, I know that my node is a call to a function.

In a second time, I need to check if this function is a native javascript function. For that, I need to find the Definition of the Node (ie where `slice` function is defined in the example). I find this information in the `Symbol` relative to the node.

In a third time, I search the path of the file which is declaring this function. If this path matches with `/typescript\/lib/`, it is a native typescript (or javascript) function.

I do these operations with the excellent library [ts-morph](https://ts-morph.com/), but it's possible to use the native `ts` library, of course.

```
   /**
    * Checks if a node is a call to a function or method
    * Example : a.slice(1)
    * @param node      // The node to check
    */
  isFunctionCall(node: Node): boolean {
       return node?.getParent()?.getParent()?.getKind() === SyntaxKind.CallExpression && isSecondSon(node);
   }


   /**
    * Checks is a given node is the second son of its parent
    * @param node      // The node to check
    */
   isSecondSon(node: Node): boolean {
       if (!node?.getParent()) {
           return false;
       }
       return node?.getChildIndex() === 2;
   }

if (isFunctionCall(node)) {
   const identifier = node as Identifier;
   const definition = identifier.getDefinitions()?.[0];
   const path = definition.getSourceFile().getFilePath();
   return path.match(/typescript\/lib/);
}
```

I hope that this will help someone.